# Upgrade python from 3.7.x to 3.10.x using BREW on Mac 13.3.1 (a)

Tags: macos, python-3.10

Trying to upgrade my python version, but I think I'm missing something significant.

```
$brew install python@3.10
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
########################################################################################################################################################################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: python@3.10 3.10.11 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.10.11, run: brew reinstall python@3.10
$ python3 --version       
Python 3.7.9
```

Comment: Looks like a path issue most likely. Maybe start with `which python3`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out earlier i had installed v3.7 **without** brew and now I was trying to install v3.10 with brew.

When it was not working, it was like this:

```
python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

After I installed it directly (from https://www.python.org/downloads), changed into like this:

```
python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
```

$python3 --version
Python 3.10.11